# regex: How to escape backslashes and special characters?

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to escape ( or protect )  special characters in a regular expression?

What I would like to do is to create a simple regex tester:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class TestRegex { 
   public static void main( String ... args ) { 
       System.out.printf("%s ~= %s ? %s  %n" , args[0], args[1], Pattern.matches( args[0], args[1] ) );
   }
}
```

Which works great to test my patterns before plug-in them into the program:

```
$java TestRegex "\d" 1
\d ~= 1 ? true  
$java TestRegex "\d" 12
\d ~= 12 ? false  
$java TestRegex "\d+" 12
\d+ ~= 12 ? true  
$java TestRegex "\d+" a12
\d+ ~= a12 ? false  
$java TestRegex "\d+" ""
\d+ ~=  ? false
```

The next thing I do is to use this pattern in my program, but each time I have to manually escape it:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( /*copy pasted regex here */ );
```

And in this sample, substitute: `\d` with `\\d`. After a while this becomes very irritating .

Q. How can I automatically escape these special characters?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just need to replace all single backslashes with double backslashes.  This is complicated a bit since the `replaceAll` function on `String` really executes a regular expression and you have to first escape the backslash because it's a literal (yielding `\\`), and then escape it again because of the regular expression (yielding `\\\\`).  The replacement suffers a similar fate and requires two such escape sequences making it a total of 8 backslashes:

```
System.out.printf("%s ~= %s ? %s  %n", 
    args[0].replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\"), args[1], ...
```

Comment: I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1`  http://pastebin.com/aEWSibXv

Comment: It's moments like these that I wish Java had a better syntax for literal Strings.

Comment: @Oscar: oops, you have to escape once for a String literal and another time because `replaceAll` is in itself a regular expression. Fixed now.

Comment: I was a couple of \ far.. I was trying several combinations :)  What about special char, like + { ( etc. ?  I don't think I need to scape those do I?

Comment: @Oscar: nope, the only literals that would cause you problems are the backslashes. Ironically the error I made is identical to the one you're trying to solve.

Comment: Which pretty much probes the point ;)  Woks like charm thanks: http://pastebin.com/y0mePwV5