# Java replaceAll("\\s+") vs replaceAll("\\\\s+")

Tags: java, replaceall

What's the difference between `replaceAll("\\s+")` and `replaceAll("\\\\s+")`? Usually I use `\\s+` but sometimes I see `\\\\s+`.

Comment: \ is written as \\ in Java. This should help you.

Comment: This should help to solve your problem:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653831/regex-how-to-escape-backslashes-and-special-characters

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`\\s+` --> replaces 1 or more spaces.

`\\\\s+` --> replaces the literal `\` followed by s one or more times.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "\\sbas  def";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\\\s+", ""));

}
```

O/P :

```
\sbas  def
\sbasdef
 bas  def
```

Comment: "...followed by s one or more times." Do u mean symbol "s" or spaces?

Comment: But where is the first "\" here "\sbasdef"?

Comment: @MaximGotovchits - the character `s` not spaces. The first `\\` will be escaped.

Comment: It also removes control characters like new line, tab, etc. Example: " \r \n\n \t ".replaceAll("\\s+","" ).length() == 0 >> true