# How to make clojure.string/replace convert "a.b.c" to "a\.b\.c"?

Tags: clojure

I am struggling to get the character sequence `a.b.c` to become `a\.b\.c` with clojure.string/replace.

Given that...

```
(clojure.string/replace "a.b.c" #"\." "|")
=> "a|b|c"
```

Why doesn't the following fail to produce `a\.b\.c`?

```
(clojure.string/replace "a.b.c" #"\." "\\.")
=> "a.b.c"
```

I can get the effect I am looking for, all `.` in a string get replaced with an escaped `.` like `\.`...

```
(clojure.string/replace "a.b.c" #"\." {"." "\\."})
=> "a\\.b\\.c"
```

...but, yuk.  There has got to be something about character escaping in Clojure strings that I'm just not getting.

Comment: Are you trying to escape a regex? There are much better ways to do that, if so.

Comment: @amalloy I am trying to dynamically build a regex.  What are the "much better ways"?

Comment: Well for example [`Pattern/quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to replace all instances of `"."` with `"\\."`, you can do this:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(str/replace "a.b.c" "." "\\.")
;;=> "a\\.b\\.c"
```

Comment: So my issue was with having that second argument be a RegEx pattern rather than just a straight up String?  The second argument somehow influenced the third?  That's, uh, subtle.  Nice answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @BobKuhar A regex as the second argument *is* legal, as explained in my answer. However, the different "overloads" have different capabilities. Consider `(clojure.string/replace "Almost Pig Latin" #"\b(\w)(\w+)\b" "$2$1ay")`, which returns `"lmostAay igPay atinLay"`.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with `replaceAll` getting called under the hood, which requires double-escaping. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653831/regex-how-to-escape-backslashes-and-special-characters) for more detail. To fix your original, either go with [Sam Estep's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38908598/6090373) and use strings, or to follow through with your original attempt using regex and a string:

```
(clojure.string/replace "a.b.c" #"\." "\\\\.")
=> "a\\.b\\.c"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you only need to escape the backslash `\` when it is inside of a string literal denoted by double-quotes, eg "\\" for a 1-char string of `\`.

Clojure allows you to have single character literals that are sometimes easier to deal with.

```
> (def bs \\)
> bs
\\
> (println bs)
\
> (prn bs)
\\
> (str bs)
"\\"
```

Note that when it is in a string (using `str`), or ready to be interpreted as a string (using `prn`), clojure prints out the escaped version. But, for `println` it prints the unescaped version.

We can avoid all the escaping if we start off with character literals like `bs` and dot `\.`

```
> (def str-dot (str \.))
> (def str-bs-dot (str \\ \.))

> str-dot
"."
> str-bs-dot
"\\."

> (println str-dot)
.
> (println str-bs-dot)
\.

> (println (str/replace "a.b.c" str-dot str-bs-dot))
a\.b\.c
```

Answer (score 0):

also, there is a special syntax for regex replacements: you can replace matched data by using `$n` syntax (where n is the index of the group matched by regexp):

```
user> (clojure.string/replace "asd.sdf.dfg" #"\." "\\\\$0")
"asd\\.sdf\\.dfg"
```

in this trivial case it is really like @Sam Estep's answer, but it becomes handy when you want to replace different chars in one pass:

```
user> (clojure.string/replace "a[s|d.sd]f.d|fg" #"[\.\|\[\]]" "\\\\$0")
"a\\[s\\|d\\.sd\\]f\\.d\\|fg"
```

or for example (rather synthetic one) you want to escape char marked with some indicator before it:

```
user> (clojure.string/replace "asd <esc>. ... <esc>| <esc>["
                              #"<esc>(.)" "\\\\$1")
"asd \\. ... \\| \\["
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just repl output different, actually it is yelling the correct result.

```
; the string auto escaped in repl display
boot.user=> (clojure.string/replace "a.b.c" #"\." "\\\\.")
"a\\.b\\.c"
; the same string displayed using println function
boot.user=> (println (clojure.string/replace "a.b.c" #"\." "\\\\."))
a\.b\.c
nil
```