# Regex: What do i need to do if i want to find "\" and "s" in a given pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I know \s helps to find whitespace character but what do i need to to find "\" and "s" in a given string ?

BOTH:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[s\]");
```

and,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\s]");
```

gives illegal escape character error .

Comment: Ask the question properly, your question is very confusing..

Comment: Maverick_Mrt    I want to find a backslash and a character "s" in a string . How can i do that ?   I want to find "\s" in a string "\s\s\saaabs\s" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` again, to be parsed as a literal backslash character:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[s\\\\]");
```

Note that I used `\\\\` instead of just `\\` because, `\\s` would actually translate to `\s` in the pattern, which will look for white-space characters.

You can also read about this [behaviour here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html).

---

Based on your [recent comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933654/regex-what-do-i-need-to-do-if-i-want-to-find-ans-s-in-a-given-pattern/39933723?noredirect=1#comment67149343_39933654), you do not need the character set either.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\s");
```

Comment: Why do i need 4 backslash, can't i just  use 2 backslash                                 :   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[s\\\]");

Comment: @SmithThapa Go through the "_Special Characters and Programming Languages_" section on http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html and also read the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4653831/1190388