# Extract some text from beginning of string

Tags: java, regex

I am stuck to solve this problem: Given a string, which might contain some information at the beginning but this information is totally optional. The format is `"//<some text>\n<other text>"`, in which `"//<some text>\n"` is totally optional but it is important.

Samples are: `"//;\n123"` and `"123"`, in the first example I would like to extract `"//;\n"` and `"123"` while in second I am fine with `"123"`.

I have tried

```
"^//(.*)\\n?(.*)$"
"^\\B//(.*)\\n\\B?(.*)$"
"^(//.*\\n)?(.*)$"
```

but neither is working. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `.*` in the first half, it might 'eat' the `\`.

You can use regex `^(//([^\\]*)\\n)?(.*)$`.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(//([^\\\\]*)\\\\n)?(.*)$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("//;\\n123");
    System.out.println(matcher.matches()); //   output: true
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));  //   output: //;\n123
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));  //   output:  //;\n
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));  //   output: ;
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));  //   output: 123
}
```

Comment: Thanks but may I ask if there is any cons to capture group(2) with this expression: [^\\\]*?

Comment: @LOUDKING In fact, you need only two back slashes to match a single slash in the original String. But, you need other two to make the complier compile.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653831/regex-how-to-escape-backslashes-and-special-characters).

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex:

```
^"(\/\/.*\\n)?(.*)"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OolV3F/1)

Explanation:
`(\/\/.*\\n)?` checks for zero or one occurrence of the capturing group that starts with `\\` and ends with `\n`

`(.*)` - second capturing group that captures everything that comes between `\n` and `"`