# How to replace and split file path in java

Tags: java

I am using below code to replace `"\\in"` with `"\\"`. `"\\in"` is the folder name and it can be anything in general.

input `"C:\\Users\\Ashish.Gupta\\Documents\\in\\output\\in"`

Expected replacedPath = `"C:\\Users\\Ashish.Gupta\\Documents\\output\\"`

```java
public class Test1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String IN = "\\in";
        String SLASH = "\\";
        String path = "C:\\Users\\Ashish.Gupta\\Documents\\in\\output\\in";
        String replacedPath = path.substring(0, path.length())
                                  .replaceAll(IN, SLASH);
        System.out.println("replacedPath" + replacedPath);
        String[] batchIdPath = replacedPath.split(File.separator);
        System.out.println("batchIdPath : " + batchIdPath);
    }
}
```

Getting below ERROR:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 1 \in  ^ at
java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:2028) at
java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.escape(Pattern.java:2608) at
java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.atom(Pattern.java:2286) at
java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2159) at
java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:2069) at
java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1783) at
java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1430) at
java.base/java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1069) at
java.base/java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2939) at
Test1.main(Test1.java:14)
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Looks like OP is trying to move one directory level up, basically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter in method [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)), in class `java.lang.String`, is a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). To escape a backslash in a regular expression, you need four backslashes, i.e. `\\\\`. Refer to [regex: How to escape backslashes and special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653831/regex-how-to-escape-backslashes-and-special-characters).

I understand that you want to remove **all** directories named `in` in the source path. If so, then the following code uses string manipulation to achieve that result.
(Note: No need to call method `substring` before calling `replaceAll`.)

```java
String IN= "\\\\in";
String SLASH= "\\\\";
String path = "C:\\Users\\Ashish.Gupta\\Documents\\in\\output\\in";
System.out.println("path: " + path);
String replacedPath = path.replaceAll(IN, SLASH);
System.out.println("replacedPath: " + replacedPath);
String[] batchIdPath = replacedPath.split("\\\\");
System.out.println("batchIdPath: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(batchIdPath));
```

Running above code produces following output:

```
path: C:\Users\Ashish.Gupta\Documents\in\output\in
replacedPath: C:\Users\Ashish.Gupta\Documents\\output\
batchIdPath: [C:, Users, Ashish.Gupta, Documents, , output]
```

However, if you are using at least Java 7, then you can use [NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) instead of string manipulation.

```java
/*
 * import java.nio.file.Path;
 * import java.nio.file.Paths;
 * import java.util.Iterator;
 */
Path p = Paths.get("C:", "Users", "Ashish.Gupta", "Documents", "in", "output", "in");
System.out.println("p = " + p);
Path bip = p.getRoot();
Iterator<Path> iter = p.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Path next = iter.next();
    if (!"in".equals(next.toString())) {
        bip = bip.resolve(next);
    }
}
System.out.println("bip = " + bip);
```

Running the above code produces the following output:

```
p = C:\Users\Ashish.Gupta\Documents\in\output\in
bip = C:\Users\Ashish.Gupta\Documents\output
```

Comment: Nice answer, but why not use `for (Path next: p)` instead of the long-winded `.iterator()`?

Comment: @Abra - thanks. I have got the answer. can we make this code OS independent as it seems to be windows specific. becauase most of the production systems runs on linux muchines.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is to replace `replaceAll` with `replace`:

```
    String replacedPath = path.replace(IN, SLASH);
```

(btw I've removed the `substring` call too, I don't know why you had it there in the first place.)

The reason your `replaceAll` didn't work was that `replaceAll` uses regex. And there is no such escape `\i` in regex. You just want to treat the string `\in` as a normal string to be replaced. The `replace` method does that (and, yes, it does replace all occurrences).

However, note that this will change, for example, `C:\Users\Ashish.Gupta\Documents\in\output\india` to
`C:\Users\Ashish.Gupta\Documents\output\dia` which you don't want.

To do this replacement properly, you can use `Path` and split into into components, and filter out any component named "in":

```
Path replacedPath = StreamSupport.stream(path.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(not(Path.of("in")::equals))
        .reduce(path.getRoot(), Path::resolve);
```

This use of Path works just as well in Linux/Unix as it does in Windows.

**Edit**

To split the path into components instead (as per the question):

```
Path replacedPath = StreamSupport.stream(path.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(not(Path.of("in")::equals))
        .map(Path::toString)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Result: `String[] {"C:", "Users", "Ashish.Gupta", "Documents", "output"}`

Comment: that works very well but this is incomplete answer. this logic will not split after replace

Comment: @AshishGupta added code to split into array of path components.

Answer (score 0):

[Abra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71764064/507738) works very well.

For completeness' sake, here is a version using the Streams API:

```java
Path p = Path.of("C:", "Users", "Ashish.Gupta", "Documents", "in", "output", "in");
Path bip = StreamSupport.stream(p.spliterator(), false)
    .filter(element -> !"in".equals(element.toString()))
    .reduce(p.getRoot(), Path::resolve);
System.out.println("bip = " + bip);
```

Comment: that works very well but this is incomplete answer. this logic will not split after replace.