# How to replace and split file path in java that makes the code platform independent

Tags: java

This is a follow up question for [replace and split path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71762807/how-to-replace-and-split-file-path-in-java/71764064#71764064)

What are the changes needed to make it platform independent. so this solution will work for windows and linux machines. because the below code works very well in windows.

```
String IN= "\\\\in";
String SLASH= "\\\\";
String path = "C:\\Users\\Ashish.Gupta\\Documents\\in\\output\\in";
System.out.println("path: " + path);
String replacedPath = path.replaceAll(IN, SLASH);
System.out.println("replacedPath: " + replacedPath);
String[] batchIdPath = replacedPath.split("\\\\");
System.out.println("batchIdPath: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(batchIdPath));
```

Comment: If you want it (as) platform-independent (as possible in Java), use `java.nio` as [already adviced in the accepted answer of the predecessing post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71764064/1712135). That way, you can handle the directory structure independently from the format of the path.

Comment: *"the below code works very well in Windows"* – No, it doesn't. That code causes `batchIdPath` to contain an empty String element, which you may have to manually filter out.

Comment: Also, as advised in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71764167/13963086), this doesn't work very well because, for example, it would replace `"C:\\docs\\indrect"` to `"C:\\docs\\direct"`. And in any case, why use `replaceAll()` with a regex escaped to make it literal, when you can simply use `replace()`?